# Trying to copy data to a new table with different schema, requires a datetime

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to copy table data. I'm trying to copy from `[old_db].[customers]` to `[new_db].[customers]`. I'm running into a problem because the new table has a `created_at` column and requires a time stamp. I can't seem to figure out how to copy the data and provide the datetime for the new table.

What I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO new_db.dbo.customers(customer)
   SELECT (customer) 
   FROM old_db.dbo.customers;
```

How would I set `[new_db].[dbo].[created_at]` to now??

Thanks!

Comment: Is the column really using the data type `TIMESTAMP`? This is just a binary value ([look up `ROWVERSION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)); you can't set it to now. If it is a datetime column, please edit your question to remove references to `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Edited. The Laravel framework referred to them as timestamps in the migrations, and I'm not familiar with SQL terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - just supply a value to that column:

```
INSERT INTO new_db.dbo.customers(customer, created_at)
   SELECT 
       customer, GETDATE() 
   FROM 
       old_db.dbo.customers;
```